# How to add a custom to Save Action

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-backpack

I need to know, how to add (display) a custom action option on Button Save, ex: 'Save and Send' on Backpack for Laravel.
I need to save and send mail after it.

Comment: Hi @niltonmelox: can you show us the code that you have so far?

Comment: It's ok now. Thks @vince-horst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this is to edit the file: `\resources\views\vendor\backpack\crud\inc\form_save_buttons.blade.php` and add another `li` element, after the `@endforeach`;

```
...
@endforeach
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-value="save_and_send">Save and Send</a></li>
```

Note the `data-value` as `save_and_send`. This is a custom event to be caught by the `store/update` function on the CrudController.

So on your `EntityCrudController`, change you store and update action to something like this:

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
    if(session('save_action') == 'save_and_send') {
        // Add you send mail code here
    }

    return parent::updateCrud();
}
```

Do the same for the for the store function if you need.

This is not going to store `'save_and_send'` action on your session for future actions, to do that you would need to extend the `Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudFeatures\SaveActions` trait.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @ToniAlmeida

Answer (score 0):

in laravel backpack 4.0 I use this, and it works.

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation {update as traitUpdate ;}

public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
    if(\Request::input('save_action') == 'save_and_send') {
        // Add you send mail code here
    }

    return $this->traitUpdate();
}
```